# random numbers after a ? on an image is this for far expires headers?

Tags: apache, optimization, http-headers

I was pooking around a random site on the internet and noticed that on the images they have numbers prefixing it: icons-16.png?1292032550

I've heard of people optimising websites with far expires headers. If someone changes the content that doesn't change very often, the cache won't get refreshed. Ergo this new image won't get re-downloaded to someones cache. Because the filename has to change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the intent is probably to force a refresh of the browser cache.  However, **I do not recommend this approach**:

- Many proxies (and possibly some browsers) simply will not cache *anything* with a query string, regardless of `Cache-Control` headers.  You're shooting yourself in the foot if you include a superfluous query string – you'll needlessly consume your own bandwidth sending images that should be cached, but aren't.
- Depending on how you configure your server, user agents will periodically make a request for cached resources, with a `If-Modified-Since` and/or `If-None-Match` header.  If the client's cache is up to date, the server responds with `304 Not Modified` and stops; otherwise it responds with a normal `200 OK` and sends the new content.  You do *not* have to change a resource's file name in order for client caches to be updated when the resource changes. Trying to get clever with a query string only serves to defeat caching mechanisms.
- That said, if you do optimize caching by setting an `Expires` date a year out (and if the `Last Modified` date of the resource is long ago), user agents may check for updates infrequently.  If this is unacceptable to you, you have two options: either reduce the amount of time before the resource expires (so that the browser will issue a `GET` request and you can respond with `304` or `200` as appropriate), or use "URL fingerprinting," where a random token is included in the **path**, instead of in the query string.  For example:

  ```
  /img/a03f/image.png
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  /img/image.png?a03f
  ```

  This way, your resources are still cached by proxies.  You'll probably want to look in to using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to allow you to include a token in the path.  Of course, you need to be able to change all references to this URL whenever you change the resource.

For further reading, I highly recommend [Google's page speed best practices](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html), specifically the section on [optimizing caching](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One way to get around caches is to append an otherwise inconsequential query parameter, such as a time stamp, to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to compensate for your web server e.g. not generating the correct ETag headers when your content changes. Using ETag with a value like the file's hash will be a better approach for telling the browser that some content has changed and it must be reloaded.